# Ignore patch version in nuget packages

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a .net application that uses the nuget package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson** with the version 6.0.22.

The app then gets installed on a Windows 11 system in the Folder "C:\Programs (x86)\MyCompany\MyApp"

When starting the app, it breaks because it cannot find the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll with the Version 6.0.22.

On the Windows System the Microsoft Windows Desktop Runtime - 6.0.23 (x86) is installed and the ASP.Net Core Runtime 6.0.12.

How can I configure my project to ignore the patch version of the nuget package or to use the correct version that is installed on the system?

Comment: So the problem is that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll 6.0.22 can't be found, you only have ASP.Net Core Runtime 6.0.12 installed, it's lower than 22, and Microsoft Windows Desktop Runtime is a distinct item.

Comment: The error is indicating that the .net Runtime Version is false. Is this a misleading error?

CoreCLR Version: 6.0.2323.48002
.NET Version: 6.0.23
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, Version=6.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: The error is "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, Version=6.0.22.0...", it's a nuget package, so you should see Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll along with your .exe file in the same folder.

Comment: Yes its there, the funny thing is, when i change the version to 6.0.12 of the nuget package it seems to work

Comment: It could work mostly, unless you use something that is only available in the new version.